# MySQL echo number of records that has the same session id

Tags: php, mysql

My table is 'gallery_list' and columns are ID, sessionid, emailedto, and date.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT sessionid, emailedto, date FROM gallery_list ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='?gallery=".$row['sessionid']."'>VIEW GALLERY SELECTION</a></td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['emailedto']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$record_count."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

This query works just fine, but how can I echo the quantity of records that contain the same sessionid? For example 4 records may contain the same sessionid, I just want to display the number 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/counting-rows.html

So your query would be

```
SELECT session_id, COUNT(*)
FROM gallery_list
GROUP BY session_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  sessionid, count(*) as count, emailedto, date FROM gallery_list GROUB By sessionid ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: As emailedto and date are not in the groupby this sql will throw an error

Comment: I tested a similar query in MySQL 5.1.52 and it worked fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: My apologies. It doesn't throw an error however the number of rows returned will only be as many as the number of unique session ids and the extra data (emailedto and date) will be for any one of the rows matching that session

Comment: Yes you are right. This may or may not be what is desired.