# PHP Row and Column Count

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if you guys can help me, I am pulling Data from a mysql database and I am looking to have the content echo in rows, like a shopping cart.  Below is the code I am using.  The Code is working flawlessly, but I don't know how to add the Row Count to it and Column Count to it.

Working Code:

```
<?
    $dmealh = mysql_query("select count(*) from jobs_cart where mid='$mid'");
    $jmealh = mysql_fetch_array($dmealh);           
    if ($jmealh[0]) { 
        $dmealh = mysql_query("select * from jobs_cart where mid='$mid' order by date desc, time desc"); 
        while ($jmealh = mysql_fetch_array($dmealh)) {
            echo "$id - $jmealh[name] - $jmealh[meals]";
        }
    }
?>
```

This is what I want the Data to look like:

```
Row Count- Name - Meal Count
       1 - Greg - 3
       2 - Mike - 4
       3 - Tomm - 1
                  8 Meals Total
```

Comment: Use the power of HTML tables. `<table><tr><td>` etc. if that's what you're looking for, formatted the way you have it as ***"This is what I want the Data to look like:"***

Comment: I usually use div tags, to make it easy to explain myself, I left out the HTML tags.

Comment: Careful. Some Div CSS3 purist may come in and call you old

Comment: For what I program I need div tags instead of tables.  Plus which ever I use anyways, really doesn't matter in terms or my question.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to show the counts then. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21689080/ - had you been using `mysqli_*` functions, I could've given you a fast answer. Yet, since you're using `mysql_*` I'd have to totally reformat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a basic counter to keep track of what row you are on and use another variable to add up the meal count as you loop through your results and then echo out the final count. Throw it all into a table and you're set.

```
<?php
$dmealh = mysql_query("select count(*) from jobs_cart where mid='$mid'");
$jmealh = mysql_fetch_array($dmealh);           
if ($jmealh[0]) { 
    $dmealh = mysql_query("select * from jobs_cart where mid='$mid' order by date desc, time desc"); 
    $total_meals = 0; // Keep track of the total number of meals. Start at zero.
    $row = 1;         // Keep track of current row. Start at one.
?>
<table>
<?php
    while ($jmealh = mysql_fetch_array($dmealh))  {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jmealh['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jmealh['meals']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php    
        $total_meals += $jmealh[meals];  // Add to total meals 
        $row++;                          // Increase row count
    }
?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $total_meals; ?> Meals Total</td>
</tr>    
</table>
}
```

Comment: I can't write this for multiple reasons, first off I know that the mysql is depreciated, because my webserver can't be updated to the latest php yet.  So my webserver doesn't know what mysqli is.  Second Like I said above, that I gave everyone the basic core.  I have alot more code to this.  If I was to change to this layout, would cause me to re-write the entire page.  Is there a possible way to add to my code, instead of me re-writing my code.

Comment: I think you added this comment to the song answer

Comment: Sorry about that I was answering two answers in one response.

Comment: @user3299699: What version of PHP are you running? Are you sure it's not available? Mysqli was introduced in PHP 5, which came out about ten years ago. And the layout is just a small detail. I had already written my answer when you said in your comment that you couldn't use an HTML table. If you need setting it up using divs, I can update my answer, but I figured you could probably get that part on your own.

Comment: I replaced your table tags with my div tags and it worked.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `mysql_*` functions...[they're deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (note the red box near the top).
2. Where does `$mid` come from? Make sure to escape your database inputs to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).
3. You're doing extra work by first querying to see if any rows are returned. Just do the SELECT query and while loop. If no rows are returned, the loop will not execute.
4. You should be using an HTML table to display this data. Use PHP variables to keep track of your sums.

A crude example:

```
$mid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mid);

$rows = $total = 0;
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT name, meals FROM jobs_cart WHERE mid = '$mid' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC");
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows++;
    $total += $row['meals'];
    echo '<tr><td>'. $rows .'</td><td>'. $row['name'] .'</td><td>'. $row['meals'] .'</td></tr>';
}
echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>'. $total .'</td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: $mid is a php variable that is loaded on the page already.  So when a page loads, $mid = a number.

Comment: Where does the value come from? Does it come from user input? If you get it from something like `$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc, then it needs to be sanitized before being used in a query. This is called [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: $mid does come from user input, but not for Post or Get.  I am not worried about the sql injections.  There are multiple if statements on the page, when the users clicks on a link, it reloads the page with $mid as a Number, so in the address bar you would see mid=1

Comment: So what if I modify the URL to say `mypage.php?mid='; DROP TABLE jobs_cart;--`? It doesn't matter how many if statements you have on the page. The variable must be sanitized before using it in a query. If `$mid` should always be an integer, then at least do `$mid = (int)$mid;` to ensure that it is an integer before using it in a query.

Comment: Well Like I had said, I dont have the time to re-write half the code.

Comment: To fix the SQL injection vulnerability, you don't have to *rewrite* anything. You just have to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on any of your variables that are used in a query. I'm betting you'll find time after someone drops a few of your important tables and you lose a ton of data.